# I want to implement face filter like Snapchat and instgram in Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, augmented-reality, face-detection

I have an requirement for implement face filter like Snapchat and instgram
Please guide me how to implement in android kotlin

Actual photo was like this image
[image]

Now when I open snap chat and apply filters its looks like the below image
So Same thing I want to implement in my app, This real time face filter I want to implement.

When I open the app is open camera, detect user face and from filter option select any one filter and appy on face (Augmented Reality)

So, How to implement where to start I don't know, I need guidance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You must describe the problem you are experiencing. The current description is very vague and unclear.

Comment: @IvanAbakumov Please check the description.

Comment: This is not a tutorial forum, you must most what you have tried and only then are others willing to assist. Refer to the guide on how to ask a question here on the right sidebar [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask]